# Replace characters with a count of characters

Tags: python, regex

I have `XXXXXXX99` and I'd like to replace it with `X(7)99` because there are 7 `X` characters followed by `99`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "XXXXXXX99"
>>> re.sub(r"(X+)", "X(the count)", s)
'X(the count)99'
```

Both of these:

```
>>> re.sub(r"(X+)", "X(" + len(\1) + ")", s)
>>> re.sub(r"(X+)", "X(" + len(\\1) + ")", s)
```

give:
`SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

In the general case the string could be more complicated, such as `XXXX99_999999XX99.99`. I'm going to want to focus on repeats greater than, say 5, meaning this example would become `XXXX99_9(6)XX99.99`.

Comment: If there is one thing regex is bad is then it is counting. Just don't use a regex for it even if it is theoretically possible.

Comment: Ha I thought I was going crazy !

Comment: Note that use of lambda is just one part of the problem, OP also wants to figure out the right regex to capture character repeats of 5 or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a lambda function with `len`:

```bash
>>> import re
>>> p = 'XXXX99_999999XX99.99'
print (re.sub(r'(.)\1{4,}', lambda m: f'{m.group(1)}({len(m.group())})', p))
XXXX99_9(6)XX99.99

>>> s = "XXXXXXX99"
>>> print (re.sub(r'(.)\1{4,}', lambda m: f'{m.group(1)}({len(m.group())})', p))
'X(7)99'
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/yZgRH5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(.)`: Match any character
- `\1{4,}`: Match 4 or more repeats of the same character

Answer (score 3):

This is something that `itertools.groupby` would be better at handling:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = "XXXXXXX99"
r = "".join(f"{c}({len(g)})" if len(g)>2 else c*len(g) 
            for c,(*g,) in groupby(s) )

print(r) # X(7)99
```

If you want the regular expression to be more explicit on the threshold length, you could write it like this:

```
re.sub(r"(?=(.))\1{5,}",lambda m:m.group(1)+f"({len(m.group())})",s)
```

This uses a lookahead `(?=(.))` to make a capture group `(.)`, then uses that group to find the repeating pattern `\1{5,}` of the given minimum size (5 in this example)

Comment: One thing I like about this solution is `len(g)>2` is explicit about how many you need in a row before they are grouped. The accepted solution is shorter and perhaps a bit easier to follow but the number there (4) actually means we are grouping by 5 or more.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
def replace_with_count(s, char):
    count = s.count(char)
    return f'{char}({count}){s.replace(char, "")}'

s = 'XXXXXXX99'
print(replace_with_count(s, 'X'))
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It works *only* in the example structure like you show, and goes wrong e.g. if character occurrences are not consecutive. String is not a bag, strings are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

```
code_1 = "XXXXXXX99"

code_2 = "AAAABB99"

def simplify(code:str)->str:
    num_part = []
    str_part = []
    for char in code[::-1]:
        if char.isdigit():
            num_part.append(char)
        else:
            str_part.append(char)
    prefix = ""
    for i in sorted(set(str_part), key = str_part.index, reverse=True):
        prefix += f"{i}({str_part.count(i)})"
    return prefix + "".join(num_part)

simplified_code = simplify(code_1)

print(s_code)
```